# Codeigniter Parser inside another Parser

Tags: codeigniter, parsing

I'm using Codeigniter for a project, I have this current code to load the main page thru the parser, and load the top and side menu with the load view:

```
public function index(){

    $main = [
        'main_nav' => $this->load->view('nav/main_nav', NULL, TRUE),
        'top_nav' => $this->load->view('nav/top_nav', NULL, TRUE),
    ];

    $this->parser->parse('main_view', $main);
}
```

In this way I can change the nav once and they change in all pages.
I need to do it thru "parser" because I have to pass some variables and functions I made.

If I change the `main_nav` and `top_nav` with parser instead of view I get an error.

Is there a way to load a parser inside another parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you cannot pass a `NULL` as the second parameter for Parser, has to be an array (can be empty, but cannot be left out).

So this:

```
$this->load->view('nav/main_nav', NULL, TRUE);
```

becomes this:

```
$content = [];
$this->parser->parse('nav/main_nav', $content, TRUE);
```

or

```
$this->parser->parse('nav/main_nav', [], TRUE);
```